# Como pegar o dia 29 de fevereiro datetime php

Tags: php, datetime

Não sei se é um bug, pesquisei, não encontrei. Mas hoje, preciso recuperar um dado de um mês atrás e para minha supresa aconteceu isso:

```
    $dateTime = new DateTime();
print_r($dateTime);
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-03-30 20:56:09.760949
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
$dateTime->modify('-1 month');
print_r($dateTime);
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-03-01 20:56:09.760949
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
```

e se recuperar um dia anterior funciona normalmente:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2020-03-29 20:00:00');
print_r($dateTime);
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-03-29 20:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
$dateTime->modify('-1 month');
print_r($dateTime);
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-02-29 20:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
```

e percebi dia 30 e 31 de março não retornou 29 de fevereiro. Alguém tem alguma solução para este problema?

Comment: Não é bug, dá uma olhada no exemplo na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

Comment: valeu. obrigado

Comment: Na prática é um "bug admitido pela linguagem" :P - Nesses casos compensa pegar o mes anterior (com base no dia 1, por exemplo), e aí extrair o ultimo dia do mês corrente, ou alguma outra manobra que seja determinística. PHP é ruim pra lidar com datas. Tem bastante função, mas é um absurdo como são implementadas internamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pesquisei mais sobre o assunto e a solução que encontrei foi:

```
$hoje =  new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
$mesPassado = $hoje->modify('last day of previous month');

print_r($mesPassado->format('Y-m-d'));
```

[resolvido]

Comment: Eu abomino uso regular de DateTime do PHP, mas no cenário específico vale o +1 pela solução determinística.

Comment: Mas porque abomina o uso do DateTime no php ? O uso é largamente incentivado.

Comment: Incentivado pela praticidade e pela crença (crença mesmo, parece que quase só baseado em fé) que OOP é melhor que sem OOP, não to dizendo que procedural é melhor, nem existe este comparativo se for falar de uso geral, estou falando que OO tem hora e lugar pra usar, mas a questão que suponho q seja o comentário do Bacco é dizer como as pessoas usam isso indiscriminadamente quando poderiam usar o simples que também funciona, quero dizer tem recursos uteis dentro da classe, mas a maioria acaba nem usando e acaba q fica um uso por exagero, não é pq a maioria incentiva q eles sabem o q fazem.

Comment: Falo do incentivo. Mas por causa do OOP e nada a mais

Comment: DateTime tem um overhead imenso e desnecessário para a maior parte dos casos, e quando se alia isso a interpretação de string, o problema fica muito pior.  Nesse caso aqui, por falta de funções melhores, é aceitavel como solução (eficiência é detalhe). E DateTime não tem nada de "OOP", apesar de usar sintaxe de objeto. @GuilhermeNascimento em PHP dá pra dizer com segurança que o procedural é sempre melhor (é a unica coisa que faz sentido). OOP é diretamente relacionada à manutenção de estado, PHP é uma linguagem basicamente de script. ou seja, sem manutenção de estado. Isso já resume muito.

Comment: E eu expliquei, incentivo por motivo nenhum, pois a maioria nem sabe o que esta fazendo, só veem uma forma nova de fazer algo e até presumem q outros meios são obsoletos, mesmo que não sejam, só por presumir mesmo, a comunidade PHP é cheio de mitos (historias inventadas da cabeça e presumir coisas), lembro-me que disseram que require é mais lento que include, que include é mais rapido que include_once, o pessoal mudava os códigos por coisas assim... das mesmas pessoas que "incentivam", mas isso não é tudo, eu posso até um dia enumerar o tanto de incentivos sem fundamentos da "comunidade php"

Comment: De qualquer forma o lugar aqui não é para bate-papo, se tiver interesse em participar do chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha -- lá pode tirar suas duvidas sobre o assunto, seja bem vindo